How to change hangfire job state on successed for failed job completed with certain type exception
I want to change job state when it fails with CustomException.
I tried to create JobFilter:
public class CustomExceptionHandlingFilter : JobFilterAttribute, IServerFilter
{
    private const string StartTimeKey = "JobStartTime";

    public void OnPerforming(PerformingContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Items[StartTimeKey] = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }

    public void OnPerformed(PerformedContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.Exception != null)
        {
            if (filterContext.Exception is CustomException)
            {
                // If a CustomException was thrown, mark the job as succeeded
                filterContext.SetJobParameter("ExceptionHandled", true);
                filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;

                // Retrieve the result, latency, and performanceDuration
                object? result = null;
                long latency = (DateTime.UtcNow - filterContext.BackgroundJob.CreatedAt).Ticks;

                // Calculate the performance duration
                DateTime startTime = (DateTime)filterContext.Items[StartTimeKey];
                long performanceDuration = (DateTime.UtcNow - startTime).Ticks;

                // Mark job as succeeded
                var succeededState = new SucceededState(result, latency, performanceDuration);
                filterContext.SetJobParameter("OriginalState", filterContext.Connection.GetStateData(filterContext.BackgroundJob.Id).Name);
                
                // How to change the job state ???
                
            }
            else
            {
                filterContext.ExceptionHandled = false;
            }
        }
    }
}

I asked ChatGPT. It suggests me three options, but none of them works:
// Option 1: Set the job state using JobStorage's connection using 
(var connection = JobStorage.Current.GetConnection()) {
connection.SetState(filterContext.BackgroundJob.Id, succeededState); }

// Option 2: Set the job state using the StateChanger from the context 
filterContext.StateChanger.ChangeState(filterContext.Connection, 
filterContext.BackgroundJob.Id, succeededState);

// Option 3: Set the job state using the connection 
filterContext.Connection.SetState(filterContext.BackgroundJob.Id, succeededState);

